# SELECT ONLY special Rows

Tags: sql

i have a table like:

```
ID, Val
```

with values like:

```
1,2
1,NULL
2,NULL
3,2
```

How can I get only

```
1,2
2,null
3,2
```

which means get all rows with `val = 2`, or if row with the ID that doesn't have any `Val = 2`

Comment: But how will you filter out record `(1, NULL)`?

Comment: this is a special question

Comment: This question is incredibly confusing.

Comment: Just turn "get all rows with val = 2, or if row with the ID that doesn't have any Val = 2" into a SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret "get all rows with val = 2, or if row with the ID that doesn't have any Val = 2" as:

```
select * from table x
where x.val = 2
or not exists (select 1 from table where id = x.id and val = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select t.id, t2.val
from (select distinct id from myTable) t
left join myTable t2 on t.id=t2.id and t2.val=2
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91959/4).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `Val` = 2
   OR ( `ID` = 2 AND ( `Val` != 2 OR `Val` IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: downvoting troll appears to be in action